# Ruby: check if all array elements are equal

Tags: ruby, arrays, equality

I'm having a bit of a 'problem' with Ruby code.
I want to check if all elements of an array are equal.

For example, say I have an array of only 5s:

```
arr = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

I know I can do something like

```
arr[0] == arr[1] == arr[2] == arr[3] # == arr[4] == ...
```

but this is impossible for huge arrays and also not very Ruby-like in my opinion.
We can improve it by doing something like this:

```
def all_equal?(arr)
  for i in 0..(arr.size-2)
    if arr[i] != arr[i+1] then
      return false
    end
  end
  true
end
```

But I also think this is pretty ugly. So is there any built-in/better/shorter (more Ruby-esque) way to do this?

**TL;DR what is the shortest/most Ruby-esque way to check if an array contains only one distinct element (e.g.** `[5, 5, 5]`)**?**

Thanks.

Comment: If the elements of `arr` are all comparable with `<=>` you could do this: `arr.min==arr.max`, but this is clearly a job for `uniq`.

Comment: `arr[0] == arr[1] == arr[2]` Really? What Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could also use `.uniq`, that returns an array with no duplicates, and check the size:

```
def all_equal?(arr)
    arr.uniq.size <= 1
end
```

Comment: Imho it should be exactly 1. If it is smaller it depends on your semantics. Does an empty array have all elements equal? ;)

Comment: Indeed it is open to interpretation - for me an empty array has all elements equal, because it has no elements :) And it is not very efficient indeed, the better way would be the `for`. But often we exchange speed with prettiness in ruby, as these kind of operations are rarely the bottleneck in most applications.

Answer (score 17):

Couple of ways.

The best one:

```
array.uniq.count <= 1 # or == 1 if it can't be an empty array
```

And:

```
array == ([array.first] * array.count)
```

And:

```
(array | array).count <= 1 # basically doing the same thing as uniq
```

Also:

```
array.reduce(:|) == array.first # but not very safe
```

And if it's a sortable array, then:

```
array.min == array.max
```

And, just for sake of variety:

```
!array.any?{ |element| element != array[0] } # or array.first instead of array[0]
```

Alternatively:

```
array.all?{ |element| element == array[0] } # or array.first instead of array[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
def all_equal?(xs)
  xs.each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x == y }
end
```

Comment: Never knew that this kind of method existed in standard library. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try This ..

```
array = ["cars","cars","truck", nil]
array.uniq.compact.length == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on Ruby 3.0+:

```rb
  [1,1,1,1].minmax.reduce(&:eql?)
```

Looks pretty. Might not be the fastest though.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array and compare the first value to the last.

Comment: I like this solution. It does require that the array can be sorted/compared (which is not always the case), so I'm going to go with Luan Nico's answer.

Comment: Order an array just to check if all elements are unique is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with later versions you can just pass matching argument to `all?` without a block

```
[5, 5, 5].all?(5) # => true
```